# Fill matrix with function output R

Tags: r, function, matrix

I'm trying to fill a matrix with the outputs of a function at each instance of the matrix. I either get the error "replacement has length zero" or "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

Please help!

```
setPoint <- function(tarray, t){
    var1 <- dim(tarray)[1] #get the length of longitudes, returns a number
    var2 <- dim(tarray)[2] #get the length of latitudes, returns a number
    empty.matrix <- matrix(nrow=var1,ncol=var2)
    for (i in 1:var1) { #i is moving from 1 to 192 (longitude)
        for (j in 1:var2) { #j moves from 1 to 145 (latitude) 
            tmp.point <- tarray[i,j,]
            1my.vector <- c(1:var2)
            my.vector[j] <- thresholdYear(tmp.point, 38,t,0.8)
        }
        empty.matrix[i,] <- my.vector
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `trarray`? You say it is a matrix, but your code reads `trarray[i,j,]` at some point...

Comment: tarray is an array with dimensions (192, 145, 475) I am inputting into the function with units longitude, latitude, time. I want to get each grid point through time (so vectors) as input. Function (thresholdYear) takes that vector that outputs a year. I want to make a matrix of the year outputs of that function

Comment: Is `thresholdYear` from a package? Please consider giving a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function returns nothing. `for` loops in R return `NULL` and that's what your function returns.
Second, in the inner loop you create `my.vector`and rewrite one of its values in the next instruction. The second iteration through the loop you recreate it, therefore destroying the value of the previous iteration, etc. What it seems to me that you need to do is to create it outside the inner loop. Something like the following.

```
setPoint <- function(tarray, t){
var1 <- dim(tarray)[1] #get the length of longitudes, returns a number
var2 <- dim(tarray)[2] #get the length of latitudes, returns a number
empty.matrix <- matrix(nrow=var1,ncol=var2)
for (i in 1:var1) { #i is moving from 1 to 192 (longitude)
      my.vector <- 1:var2
    for (j in 1:var2) { #j moves from 1 to 145 (latitude) 
        tmp.point <- tarray[i,j,]
        my.vector[j] <- thresholdYear(tmp.point, 38,t,0.8)
    }
    empty.matrix[i,] <- my.vector
}
empty.matrix
```

}